# Custom Email based on Cell values in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help while building a Request Approval Flow in google Forms/Sheets

I have a data response sheet similar to like below, Column A to J headers are 
"Timestamp" "EmailAddress"  "Name" "Targets" "Account#" "Reason" "Access(Days)" "Approver"  "Approved"  "CaseID"

I have already setup a form submit email trigger to Approval body through formMule AddOn, Now I want to trigger email when Approval body approve or disapprove the request in Data response sheet.

Everytime when anyone select "Y" or "N" to column "I", script should suppose to trigger an email based on the data present in that row.

I am not an expert but tried to do it with following script and unfortunately not getting desired outcome, I set it up Current project trigger to OnEdit

```
 function sendNotification1(e) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

      if(e.range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "Y")
      {
        var name = e.range.offset(0,-6).getValue();
        var comment = e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue();
        var email = e.range.offset(0,-7).getValue();
        var case1 = e.range.offset(0,1).getValue();
        var approver1 = e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue(); 
        var subject = "Request has been Approved";
        var body = "Hi " + name + ", your Change Request number " + case1 + " has been approved by " + approver1 + " with following comments: " + "\n\r" + comment;
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

        }

        if(e.range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "N")
       {
        var name = e.range.offset(0,-6).getValue();
        var comment = e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue();
        var email = e.range.offset(0,-7).getValue();
        var case1 = e.range.offset(0,1).getValue();
        var approver1 = e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue(); 
        var subject = "Request has been Disapproved";
        var body = "Hi " + name + ", your Change Request number " + case1 + " has been Dis-Approved by " + approver1 + " with following comments: " + "\n\r" + comment;
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

      }   

    }
```

StackDriver logging showed the following error, but couldn't identify where the issue exist while referring the cell addresses.

2018-09-14 08:19:06.336 PKT
The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. at sendNotification1(Code:6)

I am able to trigger an email on any edit event with following code, but no luck with conditional edit event trigger.

```
function sendNotification1(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail("myemail@companygmail.com", "Sample subject", "Sample body");
}
```

While debugging the code, I can see the following error
TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Lines added as below
 function sendNotification1(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  if(e.range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "Y")
but still not getting email, when I ran debugger it shows 
TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")

Comment: Try changing the name of sendNotifications to onEdit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely running into the issue of the code not knowing what `range` you are referring to, because you never tell it where to look.

Add the following to the top of the function:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR SHEET NAME");
```

And it should work perfectly.

EDIT:  Here's the email I sent to myself when I tested it.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't.  I LITERALLY added those two lines to your code, set up an onEdit trigger and tested it in my sheet and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The code is working fine with another file, not sure what is wrong in that file, anyhow Ron suggestion work perfect

Comment: I have checked and noticed that the code is also work fine if I unlink the Form from the spreadsheet. Is there any specific requirement for the sheets which has form attached.